# Getting data from a direct mapped cache in prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

The predicate getDataFromCache(StringAddress,Cache,Data,HopsNum,directMap,BitsNum)
should succeed when the Data is successfully retrieved from the Cache (cache hit)
and the HopsNum represents the number of hops required to access the data from
the cache which can differ according to direct map cache mapping technique such
that:
• StringAddress is a string of the binary number which represents the address
of the data you are required to address and it is six binary bits.
• Cache is the cache using the representation discussed previously .
• Data is the data retrieved from cache when cache hit occurs.
• HopsNum the number of hops required to access the data from the cache.
• BitsNum The BitsNum is the number of bits the index needs.

getDataFromCache is always giving me false although everythings seems working  so I want someone to fix it

```
convertAddress(Binary,N,Tag,Idx,directMap):-
                                            Idx is mod(Binary,10**N),                                            
                                            Tag is Binary // 10**N.

getDataFromCache(SA,[item(tag(T),data(D),V,_)|T],Data,HopsNum,directMap,BitsNum):-
                                         convertAddress(SA,BitsNum,Tag,Idx,directMap),
                                         number_string(Tag,Z),
                                         Z==T,
                                         V==1,
                                         Data is D.

getDataFromCache(SA,[item(tag(T),data(D),V,_)|T],Data,HopsNum,directMap,BitsNum):-
                                         convertAddress(SA,BitsNum,Tag,Idx,directMap),
                                         number_string(Tag,Z),
                                         (Z\=T;V==0),
                                         getDataFromCache(SA,T,Data,HopsNum,directMap,BitsNum).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply hopsNumber is always zero
and you don't have to traverse since it's direct
you can access it using nth0 perdicate
Also you are using the T variable twice